# Are there linux distros for switches?

Tags: linux, switch, firmware, managed

There is OpenWRT, ddWRT, etc. for routers which adds tons of capabilities to your "simple" home router.

Are there any  linux distros to "convert" an unmanaged switch into a managed one?

Answer (score 2):

So far as I know unmanaged switches simply don't have anything in them to do the processing involved. There's nothing to program.

Comment: lack of hardware you mean?

Comment: Yup, I think they just have some preprogrammed rules in an integrated circuit rather than anything programmable